# why clang++ compile code while clang -x c++ fails? ncurses with std::string

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I have a problem which looks strange to me. My code is:

```
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <ncurses.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    const unsigned int refresh_time_miliseconds = 500;
    const int exit_key1 = 'q';
    const int exit_key2 = 'Q';

    initscr();                     // Start curses mode
    cbreak();                      
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);         // getch is noblocking
    noecho();                      // don't echo keyboard input
    curs_set(0);                   // make cursor invisible
    printw("To quit hit the key '%c' or '%c'\n", exit_key1, exit_key2);
    refresh();                     // Print it on the screen

    int row, col;
    getyx(stdscr,row,col);
    int counter = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    while(ch != exit_key1 || ch != exit_key1) {
        mvprintw(row, col, "Counter: %d\n", counter++);
        std::string data = "Example";
        printw("Data vector: %s\n", data.c_str());
        refresh();
        ch = getch();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(
        refresh_time_miliseconds));
    }

    endwin();                      // End curses mode
    return 0;   
}
```

It simply starts ncurses and prints both counter value and example text until user hit 'q' or 'Q' key.

I've tried to compile it with:
`clang++ -o monitor -std=c++11 -Wall monitor.cpp --verbose -lncurses`
and it works perfect, but using:
`clang -x c++ -o monitor -std=c++11 -Wall monitor.cpp --verbose -lncurses`
fails with following output:

```
clang version 3.8.1-16 (tags/RELEASE_381/final)  
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu  
Thread model: posix  
InstalledDir: /usr/bin  
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9  
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3  
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.1  
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1  
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9  
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3  
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.1  
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1  
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1  
Candidate multilib: .;@m64  
Selected multilib: .;@m64  
 "/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name monitor.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.1 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../../include/c++/6.2.1 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6.2.1 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6.2.1 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../../include/c++/6.2.1/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.1/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -Wall -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/mike/REPOS/AGH_SO_Coffee/PROBLEM -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 158 -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /tmp/monitor-9488c0.o -x c++ monitor.cpp  
clang -cc1 version 3.8.1 based upon LLVM 3.8.1 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu  
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"  
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6.2.1"  
#include "..." search starts here:  
#include <...> search starts here:  
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../../include/c++/6.2.1  
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6.2.1  
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../../include/c++/6.2.1/backward  
 /usr/local/include  
 /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.1/include  
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu  
 /usr/include  
End of search list.  
 "/usr/bin/ld" --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o monitor /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../.. -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/monitor-9488c0.o -lncurses -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o  
/tmp/monitor-9488c0.o: In function `main':  
monitor.cpp:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'  
monitor.cpp:(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'  
monitor.cpp:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'  
monitor.cpp:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const'  
monitor.cpp:(.text+0x237): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'  
monitor.cpp:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'  
monitor.cpp:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'  
/tmp/monitor-9488c0.o:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'  
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've noticed that if I comment out all references to std::string:

```
std::string data = "Example";
printw("Data vector: %s\n", data.c_str());
```

then both compile commands success.

Do you have any ideas why I'm observing such behaviour?

Comment: It's not the compilation that's failing, it's the link.

Comment: @davmac: I agree, but isn't it the same linker for both `clang -x c++` and `clang++`?

Comment: Same linker, different libraries. `clang` doesn't link with the C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

> Patient: "When I do this, my arm hurts!"
>
> Doctor: "Don't do that!"

clang is a c compiler. It's not automatically linking the c++ runtime library (why would it?)

clang++ is a c++ compiler.

Comment: What is then the purpose of `-x c++` switch?

Comment: @Koikos the problem is not in the compiling step, it's in the linker step. by executing clang you have effectively told the linker to link to the c runtime, not the c++ runtime. Result, linker failure.

Comment: Clang's man pages says:
>clang  is  a  C,  C++,  and  Objective-C compiler  which encompasses preprocessing, parsing, optimization, code generation, assembly, and linking.[...]
>  -x <language> Treat subsequent input files as having type language. [...]
>  -stdlib=<library> Specify the C++ standard library to use; supported options are libstdc++ and libc++ [...]

It clearly says that clang should compile (and link) C++ code. I've tried both libraries libstdc++ and libc++ and both failed. This is why I've asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

Clang doesn't link with the standard C++ libraries (yes, there are more than one needed) by default.
`clang -x c++` is more intended to be used by build tools like `cmake` to supply `-lc++` and similar options.